# Boot partition problems

Tags: debian, partition, parrotsec

I am using Parrot OS and as I was installing my upgrades and updates a warning came up and said my boot partition was completely full. So, I clean up some files and try to install the upgrades again but 3 packages are being held back. So I boot into a live image on a USB and use GParted to try to extend the boot partition but it wont let me go any higher than 243 MiB. It's an 80 GB drive but I only have used 74.29 GB.

Comment: ParrotOS is Debian based therefore `sudo apt-get autoremove` can be used to routinely to remove old kernels. But ParrotOS is also geared towards security professionals that should know that? Maybe you need to start with a more user friendly distro (and not use a separated `/boot` partition)?

Comment: I already did that command along with sudo apt-get clean and my boot partition is still full, I'm still confused why I'm not able to extend the partition with gparted on a live USB? Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the command `dpkg` to clean up your boot partition , then upgrade your package to solve the held packages.

To list the `linux-image`:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
```

To purge the old `linux-image` (at least keep the latest working kernel) :

```
dpkg -P linux-image-x.y.z
```

The held package can be solved through :

```
apt dist-upgrade
```

Resizing the `/boot` partition isn't a safe way to deal with a full `/boot` partition.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you GAD3R for helping me. I purged the files like you said and went into the /boot folder and used sudo rm -r -f linux-image.x.y.z and removed the zip files that were left over. Not my /boot is freed up. Thanks for the help.